# How to search in has_many association using Sunspot/Solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Here is what my initial searchable block looks like in my User model:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  integer :sport_ids, multiple: true do
    sports.map(&:id)
  end
  integer :position_ids, multiple: true do
    positions.map(&:id)
  end
  integer :city_id
  integer :school_id
  string :state
end
```

How do I search by has_many associations? I need it to return each Athlete who has a specified ID in their sports or sport_positions. So if someone selects "Basketball" from a dropdown, ID of 2 is passed to my search method and it needs to return Athletes who have sport_id of 2 in their collection of sport_ids. Here is how sports and sport_positions are declared in the User model:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :positions, :class_name => "SportPosition", :join_table => "user_sport_positions", :uniq => true`

`has_many :sports, :through => :user_sports, order: "user_sports.created_at", class_name: "Sport"`

`has_many :user_sports`

**:::EDIT:::**

This worked for a minute after I reindexed, then all of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError (No field configured for Athlete with name 'sport_ids'):
  app/models/search.rb:12:in `block in execute'
```

here is my Search model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :coach_id, :sport_id, :gpa_min, :gpa_max, :sport_position_id, 
                  :classification, :city_id, :state, :school_id, :athlete_name

  belongs_to :coach

  def self.execute(params, page = nil)
    Sunspot.search(Athlete) do |query|
      query.with :public, true
      query.with :removed_from_listing, false
      query.fulltext params[:athlete_name] unless params[:athlete_name].blank?
      query.with :sport_ids, params[:sport_id] unless params[:sport_id].blank?
      query.with :position_ids, params[:sport_position_id] unless params[:sport_position_id].blank?
      query.with(:state).equal_to(params[:state]) unless params[:state].blank?
      query.with(:classification).equal_to(params[:classification]) unless params[:classification].blank?
      query.with :city_id, params[:city_id] unless params[:city_id].blank?
      query.with :school_id, params[:school_id] unless params[:school_id].blank?
      query.with(:current_gpa).between(params[:gpa_min]..params[:gpa_max]) unless params[:gpa_min].eql?("0.0") && params[:gpa_max].eql?("5.0")
      query.paginate page: page unless page.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

**NOTE:** To make this even more strange, I have a field called "recruit_year" that is an integer attribute. I was getting the same error on this field saying "No field configured" blah blah. That error usually only happens on `text` fields if you try to do a comparison like equal_to or treat it like a `string`.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine, the problem was STI. I had an Athlete block that was overriding the User block.